# How to use a table as a reference for another table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, import

I have code from generic SQL that I need to find out how to run in MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE firstTable
(
freq int NULL,
w1 int NULL,
w2 int NULL,
w3 int NULL
)

CREATE TABLE secondTable 
(
[wID] [int] NULL,
[w1] [varchar](50) NULL,
[w1cs] [varchar](50) NULL,
[L1] [varchar](50) NULL,
[c1] [varchar](25) NULL
)
```

The creation of the first table is simple enough, but MySQL runs into syntax errors with trying to create the second table. I know this code works in another version of SQL, but I only have access to MySQL. The data I need is in [firstTable], and I need to use [secondTable] to look up the identity of the items (coded as integers) in [firstTable].

Also, the data in [firstTable] is really large (though I do have the requisite amount of RAM)... Is there a better way of importing the data than the standard MySQL command that's designed for larger files?

Cheers, and thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Change the syntax as per mysql:

```
CREATE TABLE secondTable 
    (
    wID int NULL,
    w1 varchar(50) NULL,
    w1cs varchar(50) NULL,
    L1 varchar(50) NULL,
    c1 varchar(25) NULL
    )
```